# Make broken image respect CSS dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am clamping image sizes with CSS:

```
#somewhere img {
   width: 160px;
   height: 90px;
}
```

When all images load properly, my page layout looks good. On the other hand, if any particular image does not load, my page layout gets screwed up because the broken image will occupy 0px by 0px. Elements around that broken image will scrunch upwards. How do I make broken images still respect the CSS dimensions so my layout doesn't collapse?

[image: broken image]

Comment: Are you sure you're selecting the right image with your CSS? Is this a cross browser issue? What other CSS is on the page?

Comment: An image could not load if a user types in the wrong URL or if the server deleted a valid image.

Comment: @Josh : I am sure the CSS is targeting the images. My screenshot shows a 16x16 icon clamping to 160x90. However, the purposely broken image does not clamp to 160x90 even with HTML width and height attributes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adding `display: block` to `img` should be good enough:

```
#somewhere img {
   width: 160px;
   height: 90px;
   display: block;
}
```

---

If that somehow doesn't work, then wrapping the `img` in another element *will work*.

```
<span><img class="channelLogoImg" width="160" height="90" src="" /></span>

#somewhere span, #somewhere img {
   width: 160px;
   height: 90px;
   display: block;
}
```

I chose `span` because that's the usual choice for frivolous wrappers.

Comment: I'm going with the `display:block` method because it's cleaner and the layout works with a block image.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your layout, maybe you can add CSS property

```
display: [block/inline-block]
```

to "img" tag.

Or you can make div/span wrapper around images and give them fixed height and width like:

```
<div style="height:90px; width:160px">
    <img src="foo.jpg" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a CSS solution but I would always specify the width and height attributes of the image tag rather than in CSS - this will resolve your scrunching issue for missing images.

Comment: This does not work in Firefox 5 (at least) when I dynamically create the img with Prototype: `new Element('img', {width:160, height:90, src:'doesNotExist.jpg'});`. The image still does not occupy finite space.